# Comma delimited Text failed to read my imported CSV file columns

Tags: qgis, csv, import, delimiter

As you can see after saving my Excel file as CSV (comma delimited) and importing it to the Add delimited layer tool in QGIS, it failed to read the 4 columns and instead read it as 1 single column.

Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the upper part (file format), click "custom delimiters" instead of "CSV (comma separated values)" and choose the semicolon as delimiter. Your fields are apparently divided by semicolons, as you can see in your screenshot.

Comment: THANK YOU !! It works exactly as you described.

Comment: @Oisif, please accept one of the answers as a valid one with a green tick. So, it will help other users in future to handle the same problem much more efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

Since your **comma** separated value file is separated with semi-colons it is clear why QGIS is confused. If you want to use a **custom** separator like a semi-colon then you should select custom separator.